# Can not through Java client query hive which is source from hbase

Tags: java, hadoop

We have Hive which is sourced from Hbase。Then i use java client to query the data from hive.I got this exception:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:559)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1412)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.FetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:372)
    at com.test.HiveConnect.main(HiveConnect.java:46)
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error retrieving next row
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:396)
    at com.test.HiveConnect.main(HiveConnect.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:559)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1412)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.FetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:372)
    ... 1 more
```

I add all jars (in %HIVEPATH%/lib) into my classpath,my code is :

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class HiveConnect {
     private static String driverName =
        "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hive2://10.0.2.6:10000/nuoyuan", "hive", "Hd@!2017");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "zm_info";
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }

    // describe table
    sql = "describe " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }


    sql = "select * from " + tableName;
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue,thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure your Hive Metastore and HBase services are up and running? And did you try to make the same request from hive cli?

Comment: Yes，I can get data from hive cli and also can get data from spark.

Comment: If hive source from HDFS directly,  I can  get the data use the same codes.